# Introduction part interleaved with the abstract and i am using elsarticle class

Tags: elsarticle

I am using the following class and packages to write my paper

```
%\documentclass[3p,times,procedia,twocolumn]{elsarticle}
\documentclass[preprint,3p,times,twocolumn]{elsarticle}
%\documentclass[3p,times]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{ecrc}
%\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,graphicx,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage[caption]{subfig}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{picins}
%\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\include{pythonlisting}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=simple}
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{(\alph{subfigure})}
\volume{00}
\firstpage{1}


\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}

\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}
%\dochead{}
\title{ABCDEFGHIJKL}

\author[rvt]{AWAW\corref{cor1}}
\ead{awq}
\author[ade]{AQAQ\corref{cor2}}
\ead{asw}
\cortext[cor1]{AWAW}
\cortext[cor2]{AQAQ}

\address[rvt]{XYZ}
\address[ade]{XYZ}
\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{abstract}
\begin{keyword}
A;B;C;D.
\end{keyword}
\end{frontmatter}

%\begin{linenumbers}
\section{INTRODUCTION}

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

but the problem is arising the abstract part is merged with the introduction part, I am uploading the snapshot of it as you can see the horizontal line (abstract section) is interleaved with the introduction section !

[image: snapshot]

Comment: We will need to see a fuller example of your input to be able to help: there is no reason from the document class line to expect the issue you are seeing.

Comment: What's the reason for loading the package `fullpage` -- do you want to override the page parameters of `elsarticle`? And why do you load both `graphicx` and `graphics`?

Comment: I removed the above mentioned packages but the error is same i.e. fullpage and graphics

Comment: What/where is `ecrc.sty`?

Comment: Thanks for posting a complete code example. To compile it, I had to comment out the instructions `\usepackage{ecrc}`, `\volume{00}`, and `\firstpage{1}`. With these adjustments made, there is *no overlap* of the type shown in your screenshot.